# visual studio developer PowerShell detects only .NET runtime 6.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, .net-core, windows-10

I want to use developer PowerShell in visual studio 2022 prev to run some CLI commands of a framework. this framework requires .NET core app runtime version 5. However, the execution was failed with the output

```
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '5.0.0' was not found.
```

I already installed it alongside the net 6, and If I am not wrong, they are installed globally and taken the root path "C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App" but the developer PowerShell fetch the framework in the root path of visual studio not the above one. The output says it knows only version 6:

```
 - The following frameworks were found:
      6.0.0-preview.5.21301.5 at [C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\dotnet\runtime\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

the command works perfectly using the Windows PowerShell,
I am sure it is a global and developer environment question but I don't know how to solve that. Now I have to always use Windows PowerShell which is an annoying method.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by copying the NetCore.App backward version from

```
"C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App"
```

To

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\dotnet\runtime\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App"
```

I am not sure whether it is the best practice or not but it solved my problem. So I set it as accepted